# .MSI setup package installation issue, asks .NET Desktop Runtime before installation

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core, installation, setup-deployment

I have developed one WPF Application using MVVM architecture and Telerik Controls.
We have deployed this application across company now want to deploy same application with new version.

Application Framework :
.Net Core 3.1(Any CPU)

Application Setup :
Target Platform x64

Installed Prerequisite Software:

1. Microsoft .Net Core Runtime 3.1 x64
2. Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime
3. Microsoft Windows Desktop Runtime 3.1.21 x64
4. I also have .net framework 4.5.1 and 4.8 installed

My machine configuration

- Edition      Windows 10 Pro
- Version      20H2
- Installed on ‎3/‎27/‎2021
- OS build     19042.1348
- Experience   Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
- System Type   64 bit

When i tried to install .msi package of same i am getting below error
[image]

When i click on yes, it redirect me to browser and it shows below page,

[image]

Command Result :- dotnet --list-sdks

[image]

Why this error is coming when i have all prerequisite software installed?
Can someone help me to understand how to resolve it?

Edit: Added result for command:  reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP" /s

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP" /s

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\CDF

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\CDF\v4.0
HttpNamespaceReservationInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
NetTcpPortSharingInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
NonHttpActivationInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
SMSvcHostPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
WMIInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Increment    REG_SZ    4927
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1
SP    REG_DWORD    0x2
Version    REG_SZ    2.0.50727.4927

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1028
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1029
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1030
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1031
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1032
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1033
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Increment    REG_SZ    4927
SP    REG_DWORD    0x2
Version    REG_SZ    2.0.50727.4927

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1035
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1036
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1038
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1040
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1041
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1042
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1043
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1044
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1045
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1046
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1049
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1053
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\1055
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\2052
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\2070
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\3076
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\3082
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
MSI    REG_DWORD    0x1
OCM    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Increment    REG_SZ    4926
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
SP    REG_DWORD    0x2
Version    REG_SZ    3.0.30729.4926

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Servicing

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Servicing\Windows Workflow Foundation
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Hotfix    REG_SZ
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
SP    REG_DWORD    0x2
SPIndex    REG_DWORD    0x0
SPName    REG_SZ    SP2

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup
InstallSuccess    REG_DWORD    0x1
Version    REG_SZ    3.0.30729.4926

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\1033
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Increment    REG_SZ    4926
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
InstallSuccess    REG_DWORD    0x1
SP    REG_DWORD    0x2
Version    REG_SZ    3.0.30729.4926

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\Windows Communication Foundation
InstallSuccess    REG_DWORD    0x1
ReferenceInstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0
RuntimeInstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation
Version    REG_SZ    3.0.4506.4926

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\Windows Presentation Foundation
(Default)    REG_SZ    WPF v3.0.6920.4902
InstallRoot    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.0\WPF
InstallSuccess    REG_DWORD    0x1
ProductVersion    REG_SZ    3.0.6920.4902
Version    REG_SZ    3.0.6920.4902
WPFCommonAssembliesPathx64    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\System32
WPFNonReferenceAssembliesPathx64    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.0\WPF
WPFReferenceAssembliesPathx64    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\Windows Workflow Foundation
(Default)    REG_SZ    Windows Workflow Foundation
FileVersion    REG_SZ    3.0.4203.4926
InstallDir    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0
InstallSuccess    REG_DWORD    0x1
MajorBuildNum    REG_SZ    4203
ProductVersion    REG_SZ    3.0.0.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\Windows Workflow Foundation\Debugger
ControllerConduitTypeName    REG_SZ    Microsoft.Workflow.DebugEngine.ControllerConduit, Microsoft.Workflow.DebugController, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
ExpressionEvaluationFrameTypeName    REG_SZ    Microsoft.Workflow.DebugEngine.ExpressionEvaluationFrame, Microsoft.Workflow.ExpressionEvaluation, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5
SP    REG_DWORD    0x1
Version    REG_SZ    3.5.30729.4926

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\1033
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
SP    REG_DWORD    0x1
Version    REG_SZ    3.5.30729.4926

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client\1033
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\1033
CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0
(Default)    REG_SZ    deprecated

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0\Client
Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
Version    REG_SZ    4.0.0.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: Did you really install the .NET Framework 4.7.2 runtime?

Comment: No I didn't....

Comment: Did you solve the problem after installation?

Comment: No it is not allowing me to install .Net Framework 4.7.2. It give me below message on wizard. ".NET Framework 4.7.2 or a later update is already installed on this computer."

Comment: You use the dotnet --list-sdks command to post the version information to see

Comment: screenshot added in the Question

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the developer package of .NET Framework 4.7.2, click here to download and install:

1.Go to page https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework-runtime/net472.

2.Click the Download .NET Framework 4.7.2 link, and save the executable file.
Find the file in your Downloads folder, right-click it and select Run as administrator.

3.Tick the box to accept the license terms and click Install. The installation starts.

4.Once the installation is complete, click Finish.
Note: You must restart your computer to complete the installation.

Note: If the manual installation fails, check the error message. If you cannot solve the issue based on the error message, contact [F-Secure support](https://www.f-secure.com/en/web/home_global/support).

Comment: Installed 4.7.2 developer package still it throws same message on installation

Comment: You try to use this command:reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP" /s  .Check the specific information version

Comment: Added reg command result at the end of question

Comment: You already have the latest version. If you want to continue using 4.7.2, you must uninstall the newer version and install the old one. In addition, you can take a look at the version compatibility in the .NET Framework:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility

Comment: Hi Chaodeng, I unchecked the Prerequisite (.NET framework 4.7.2) from SetupProject Properties and tried installing the setup. It still gives same message.

Comment: Are you an error that occurred after uninstalling and reinstalling?